# String Height measure based on an fixed width

Tags: string, measure

I want to get the height of a string in a rectangle with a width of 280. Sometimes the String_2_Print contains a vbctrl.

```
Dim textfont = New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
Dim Txt_Width As New SizeF
Dim Printer_Y as integer = 0
Txt_Width = e.Graphics.MeasureString("1", textfont)
Dim Text_Height as integer '= the height of the string to print

e.Graphics.DrawString(UCase(String_2_Print), textfont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(0, Printer_Y, 280, Text_Height), StringFormat.GenericTypographic)
Printer_Y +=  Txt_Width.Height + Text_Height
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. You have to make a dynamic label with the same width as the rectangle you want and then you can get the label.height.

```
Dim textfont = New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
Dim Txt_Width As New SizeF
Dim Printer_Y as integer = 0
Txt_Width = e.Graphics.MeasureString("1", textfont)                

Dim myLabel As New Label
myLabel.Font = New Font("Arial", textfont , FontStyle.Italic)
myLabel.AutoSize = True
myLabel.MaximumSize = New Size(285, 0)
myLabel.Location = New Point(0, 0)
myLabel.Visible = False
myLabel.Text = The_Msg
Panel1.Controls.Add(myLabel)
Dim myMsg_Height As Integer = myLabel.Height + 1
Panel1.Controls.Clear()

e.Graphics.DrawString(The_Msg, textfont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(5, Printer_Y, 280, myMsg_Height), StringFormat.GenericTypographic)
Printer_Y += myMsg_Height + 15
```